# Multiple notifications with different data

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I have an issue with my app that i cant solve. The app takes the input(reminder) from a user and then sets it as a notification. The user can create as many notifications as he/she likes. I want the user to click the notification and get taken to a new activity(Reminder), so he/she can see the reminder in a TextView. So i have an activity(SetReminder), which let the user put his data in a text editor.Then i save his data in a hashMap. The int is the id of user's string data. Then i have a class (AlarmReceiver) which extends BroacastReceiver and generates the notification.In this class i have an id for each notification,which matches the hashMap's int from the SetReminder activity. That way i was expecting that the user would see the data of each notification.But that's doesn't happen. I have multiple Notifications(i want that), but the user sees the data of the last notification, no matter which notifications selects. I am posting the code from the three activities.
Thanks in advance.

SetReminder.class

```
    package demo.push_not_demo;


    import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.app.AlarmManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.SystemClock;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import com.kunzisoft.switchdatetime.SwitchDateTimeDialogFragment;
    import java.util.HashMap;



    public class SetReminder extends AppCompatActivity {

private SwitchDateTimeDialogFragment dateTimeFragment;
Button b1,b2,b3;
EditText editText;
public static int counter=0;
public static HashMap<Integer,String> hashMap;
private static final String TAG_DATETIME_FRAGMENT = "TAG_DATETIME_FRAGMENT";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.set_reminder);
    hashMap= new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.set_date_time);
    b2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    b3=(Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    b1.setOnTouchListener(touch);
    b2.setOnTouchListener(touch);
    b3.setOnTouchListener(touch);
    editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.reminder_edit);
}

View.OnTouchListener touch= new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.set_date_time:
                if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    v.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x77000000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    v.invalidate();
                }
                else if (event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                    v.invalidate();
                    // Construct SwitchDateTimePicker
                    dateTimeFragment = (SwitchDateTimeDialogFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_DATETIME_FRAGMENT);
                    if(dateTimeFragment == null) {
                        dateTimeFragment = SwitchDateTimeDialogFragment.newInstance(
                                getString(R.string.label_datetime_dialog),
                                getString(R.string.positive_button_datetime_picker),
                                getString(R.string.negative_button_datetime_picker)
                        );
                    }
                    dateTimeFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG_DATETIME_FRAGMENT);
                }
            break;
            case R.id.cancel:
                if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    v.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x77000000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    v.invalidate();
                    cancelalarm();
                }
                else if (event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                    v.invalidate();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SetReminder.this,HomeScreen.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            break;
            case R.id.save:
                if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    v.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x77000000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    v.invalidate();

                }
                else if (event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                    v.invalidate();
                    counter++;
                    hashMap.put(counter,editText.getText().toString());
                    alarmservice();
                }
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

public void alarmservice(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AlertReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(alarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+ 5000,pendingIntent);
}

public void cancelalarm(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AlertReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
    }
```

AlertReceiver.class

```
    package demo.push_not_demo;

    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    import java.util.HashMap;

    import static android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    import static android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH;
    import static android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC;

    public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static int id=0;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    id++;
    createNotification(context);
}

private void createNotification(Context context) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.offer1)
        .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
        .setContentText("Tap to see your reminder")
        .setPriority(PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setVibrate(new long[] { 50, 1000, 500, 1000, 1000 })
        .setDefaults(DEFAULT_SOUND)
        .setVisibility(VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context,Reminder.class);

    PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,id,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    notification.setContentIntent(pendingintent);
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification ntfc =  notification.build();
    nm.notify(id,ntfc);
}


    }
```

Reminder.class

```
    package demo.push_not_demo;


   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   import static demo.push_not_demo.AlertReceiver.id;
   import static demo.push_not_demo.SetReminder.hashMap;

   public class Reminder extends AppCompatActivity{


TextView txtv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reminder);
    txtv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.reminder_textView);
    txtv.setText(hashMap.get(id));

}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use static id,in your code id is always 0. you can check it using Log!
 use another way for produce different ids.

when you add notification with same id, the new  notification will replace with last notification. use random integer for id

Comment: how am i supposed to access a variable from another class if its not static....?
can you give me a ling on how to use Log?

Comment: and i think that if id was always 0, i wouldn't see anything in Reminder activity. and i am telling you that i can see data...but is always the last data..
Please correct me if i am wrong...

Comment: look what i was thinking...I wanted the id to be the same with the int(counter) the hashMap, so i can get the right string to be appeared in the Text View, when the user taps the notification...is this wrong?if id doesn't match the int in the hashMap, is it going the right text to be appeared? thnx in advance

Comment: put your id in intent , just search how to pass data using intent